# JavaScript equivalent of PHP mail()

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email, action

Is it possible to send an email using JS, like PHP's `mail()` function.

I know you can use `mailto` in the `action`, like this:

```
<form action="mailto:example@example.com">
  <p>Type In Your Email</p>
  <input type="email">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But that just opens up the default email program. I want to send an email to the email they entered, from a different address.

**Is there a way to send an email in JS, from a custom email address, without opening the default mail client?**

Comment: Nope, an email would have to be sent by the server. JS wouldn't work because it is on the client side.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626940/mailto-on-submit-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** You can't send an email using HTML form action. You'll need to do it using server-side languages like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Nop., with the help of only HTML you we can't send `mail()` because for sending emails we need to set server-side script so that server can send or receive requests

Answer (score 0):

You can do it it javascript or jquery.

```
<form id="frm" action="mailto:example@example.com">
<p>Type In Your Email</p>
<input id="email" type="email">
<input id="btn" type="button">
</form> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $('#btn').click(function(){ 

  $('#frm').attr('action', 'mailto:' + $('#email').val() ) ;
  $('#frm').submit();

 });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use python or ruby

...the title is misleading.

No, you'd have to use something in addition to JavaScript and html