# How can I style my mailto form results?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

So I have a basic form that takes in Name, Email, Date of Arrival, Date of Departure and Comment with a big "Send" button. Here is the code for that:

```
    <form class="form" id="form1" action="mailto:myemail@email.com" method="post">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="Name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="Email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="Date Of Arrival" type="date" class="validate feedback-input" id="date" placeholder="Date Of Arrival" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="Date Of Departure" type="date2" class="validate feedback-input" id="date2" placeholder="Date Of Departure" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="Text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It successfully opens up my mail client with an email. The issue is that this is what is in the body of the email:

```
Name+%250D%250A+=Name+Test&Email+%250D%250A=test%40email.com&Date+Of+Arrival+%250D%250A=09%2F04%2F2015&Date+Of+Departure+%250D%250A=24%2F04%2F2015&Text=This+is+a+test+comment
```

How can I style this? I have looked online and can't figure it out.

For this example, this is how I would like the email body to look:

```
Name: Name Test
Email: test@email.com
Date of Arrival: 09/04/2015
Date of Departure: 24/04/2015
Message Body: This is a test comment.
```

I wouldn't mind having the subject field repopulated too with "booking request" or something.

Thanks!

Comment: `mailto:foo@example.com?subject=Booking request` for the subject.

Comment: you can refer to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_enctype.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy. All you have to do is specify your Content Type (MIME). Change your form to:

```
<form class="form" id="form1" action="mailto:myemail@email.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Answer (score 1):

Define enctype in form tag:

```
<form class="form" id="form1" action="mailto:myemail@email.com" method="post" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately what you can do here in terms of formatting is very limited. I would suggest to have a look at this answer:

[Mailto on submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626940/mailto-on-submit-button)