# Creating a form for html

Tags: html

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">

<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
<form action="MAILTO:kenneth2461@hotmail.com" method="post" >

</form>

</div>
```

This is a website project I am doing, the problem I am having is when I click Submit, the form does not email to the email shown in the form action. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mailto on submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626940/mailto-on-submit-button)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @AllJs this is very bad formatted.

If you just want to send an email you can do this via JavaScript. You can clean the form and submit by creating events.

Below how you can send emails in different ways.

- Pure html

  ```
   <a href="mailto:name@server.com">Click here to mail</a>
  ```
- Another example with Javascript and Html

  ```
  //JavaScript
  function sendEmail() {
       window.location.href = "mailto:mail@server.com";
  }
  //HTML
  <button type="button" onClick="sendEmail()">Email!</button>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe tried to do this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:kenneth2461@hotmail.com" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="text" name="input"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form) to make forms.

Here a doc about the [`mailto` protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx).