# How to correctly submit form from SB Admin 2.0?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to development. I am trying to create a simple system using SB Admin 2.0 (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) 
When I build a form though, the submit button doesnt seem to work. I changed the method to ***GET*** and the action to ***mailto:myname@domain.com*** but it seems as if no information is being passed. 
I made sure that the button has type="submit" and that it falls within the same form, but no luck. Heres my code:

```
<form role="form" method="GET" action="mailto:myname@gmail.com">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="name">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
</form>
```

I would really appreciate assistance with this.
Thanks in advance!

*- Emma*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626940/mailto-on-submit-button) SO question.

Comment: No, the issue is that it doesnt send the information through. I believe it has something to do with the template structure